# How to avoid nesting do/catch statements in Swift2

Tags: swift2, do-catch

I keep wanting to do this:

```
do {
    let result = try getAThing()
} catch {
   //error
}

do {
    let anotherResult = try getAnotherThing(result) //Error - result out of scope
} catch {
    //error
}
```

But seem only to be able to do this:

```
do {
     let result = try getAThing()
     do {
          let anotherResult = try getAnotherThing(result) 
     } catch {
          //error
     }
} catch {
     //error
}
```

Is there a way to keep an immutable `result` in scope without having to nest do/catch blocks? Is there a way to guard against the error similar to how we use the `guard` statement as an inverse of if/else blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 1.2, you can separate the declaration of the constant from the assignment of the constant. (See "Constants are now more powerful and consistent" in the [Swift 1.2 Blog Entry](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22).) So, combining that with the Swift 2 error handling, you can do:

```
let result: ThingType

do {
    result = try getAThing()
} catch {
    // error handling, e.g. return or throw
}

do {
    let anotherResult = try getAnotherThing(result)
} catch {
    // different error handling
}
```

Alternatively, sometimes we don't really need two different `do`-`catch` statements and a single `catch` will handle both potential thrown errors in one block:

```
do {
    let result = try getAThing()
    let anotherResult = try getAnotherThing(result)
} catch {
    // common error handling here
}
```

It just depends on what type of handling you need.

Comment: I thought that would work too, but I'm getting an xCode error - Constant 'result' used before being initialized

Comment: Then you have a path in `catch` that allows the code to continue execution and reach that other line even though `result` wasn't assigned. But if you `return` or `throw` an error, you won't get that error.

Comment: Yes, That's exactly right, I didn't have a return or throw in my catch blocks so either I needed that or need to make result optional.